# javascript no me detecta click

Tags: javascript

Tengo este codigo que sirve para imprimir el outerHTML de un div,
Proceso de ejecucion:

1. detecto click en un elemento con atributo bt-print
2. selecciono el div con atributo area-print basado en el bt-print
3. creo, abro una ventana y le doy como html el outerHtml de mi div area-print
4. al imprimir o cerrar la ventana de dialogo print cierro esta ventana

```js
document.querySelector('[bt-print]').addEventListener("click",function(){
  alert(1);
var divToPrint=document.querySelector('[area-print="'+this.getAttribute('bt-print')+'"]');
var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.outerHTML+'</body></html>');
newWin.document.close();
});
```

```html
<div area-print="hola">hola</div>
<div area-print="chau">chau</div>

<button bt-print="hola">Hola</button>
<button bt-print="chau">Chau</button>
```

Funciona bien con el primer bt-print, los demas no los detecta,
puse el alert para ver si ejecuta almenos la funcion y nada
**mi pregunta es: como puedo seleccionar todos los elementos que contengan bt-print como atributo**

Nota: intente con querySelectorAll pero es peor, no detecta ni el primer boton

Otra forma de preguntar seria:
lo que deseo es obtener el mismo resultado que obtendria poniendo en jquery esto:
$("[bt-print]").on("click",function(){
...
});

Comment: ```querySelector``` te devuelve un *htmlCollection*, tendrás que recorrerlo, no te aparece algo en la consola?

Comment: Puedes usar un `getElementById`, debe devolverte un array de esos selectors y te da error porque no específica cuál vas a usar.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar lo que quieres hacer, sobre todo aquí: `var divToPrint=document.querySelector('[area-print="'+this.getAttribute('bt-print')+'"]');` ¿? Tu código es altamento sospechoso de una mala práctica o de un error de lógica.

Comment: @A.Cedano sirve para imprimir el outerhtml de un div

Comment: Entiendo, pero si de entrada explicas lo que quieres hacer podemos decirte que hay maneras más simples de hacer este tipo de cosas. No puedes vivir esclavo de un código, cuando ese código tiene una mala práctica o errores de lógica arrastras con él sín necesidad cuando puedes mejorar/optimizar. Lo digo porque veo muchas preguntas como la tuya donde te lanzan el código sin más, sin explicar nada pensando que tiene que ser con ese código obligatoriamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano recien veo el error en mi pregunta, no se copio la parte de arriba ahora corrijo eso, pero si tienes una mejor opcion para imprimir un div en especifico y que el selector sea variable o modificable directamente desde un atributo te agradeceria bastante que lo publicaras como respuesta. bendiciones

Comment: Para responder hace falta entender el problema, por ejemplo, no sé exactamente qué quieres decir con *que el selector sea variable o modificable directamente desde un atributo*. En las preguntas conviene siempre explicar brevemente el contexto, lo que quieres lograr y el problema que tienes. A veces el problema surge porque estás optando por una lógica equivocada o usando malas prácticas que en vez de ayudar enredan más las cosas. Es lo que sospecho aquí, pero si no explicas tu contexto es complicado aventurarse en una respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya corregi mi pregunta con modificable directamente me refiero a que yo pueda poner en cualquier elemento el atributo bt-print="..." y el valor de este atributo lo pueda usar como parte del selector html, esto con el objetivo de poder imprimir cualquier div que contenga el area-print sin necesidad de estar registrando uno por uno

Comment: A ver si entendí, media hora después: ¿quieres que al presionar un determinado botón el código tome el contenido del `div`  que tenga el mismo `area-print`, o sea, si se presiona el botón con `bt-print="hola"` tomar el div con `area-print="hola"`?

Comment: @IntruzO, si bien, nada te impide crear atributos personalizados (¿o arbitrarios?), lo recomendable es usar [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). En cuanto a la impresión, desconozco si hay mejores opciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano exactoooo, y si pongo bt-print="chau" me obtenga el html del div que tenga como atributo area-print="chau"

Comment: @Triby y por ejemplo como usaria los atributos data-... en este caso ?

Answer (score 2):

La [respuesta de @anythingg](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/444489/54039) explica muy bien cómo y porqué usar `querySelectorAll()` y, basado en su código, solo te propongo algunos cambios:

1. Usar [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) en lugar de crear tus propios atributos de forma arbitraria. Todos los navegadores recientes dan soporte a esta característica
2. En la medida de lo posible, evita concatenaciones y crea las cadenas con [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para mayor legibilidad y facilidad al crear contenidos
3. No es recomendable asignar eventos dentro de etiquetas, en lugar de tener `<body onload="window.print()">` usa el comando sobre la ventana creada

Desconozco si hay mejores formas de imprimir con un solo clic el contenedor deseado; las pocas veces que he necesitado imprimir, creo una ventana modal mostrando el contenido dentro de un *iframe* y el botón correspondiente, pero supongo que no es lo que buscas, porque se requiere que el usuario haga un clic adicional

```js
// Seleccionar por atributo de datos
document.querySelectorAll('[data-button]').forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Obtener contenido de atributo de datos con elemento.dataset.nombreAtributo
        let divToPrint = document.querySelector(`[data-print='${btn.dataset.button}']`);
        let newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
        newWin.document.write(`
            <html>
              <body>
                  ${divToPrint.outerHTML}
              </body>
            </html>
        `);
        // Imprimir con el comando print() en lugar de usar evento en etiqueta
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    });
});
```

```html
<div data-print="hola">hola</div>
<div data-print="chau">chau</div>

<button data-button="hola">Hola</button>
<button data-button="chau">Chau</button>
```

**Importante:** El fragmento de código no abre una ventana nueva y es por las restricciones que pone *SO* para evitar acciones que pueden suponer algún riesgo para otros usuarios (spam, rastreo, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` solo te devuelve el primer elemento con el selector, si quieres obtener todos los elementos, usa [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), el cual te da un [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) que puedes recorrer con [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[bt-print]').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert(1);
    var divToPrint=document.querySelector('[area-print="'+el.getAttribute('bt-print')+'"]');
    var newWin=open('','Print-Window');
    newWin.document.open();
    newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.outerHTML+'</body></html>');
    newWin.document.close();
  });
});
```

```html
<div area-print="hola">hola</div>
<div area-print="chau">chau</div>

<button bt-print="hola">Hola</button>
<button bt-print="chau">Chau</button>
```

Comment: Este código da error.

Comment: @A.Cedano Porque se intenta abrir una nueva ventana en un `<iframe>`, se sobreentiende que esto no se puede y no se puede leer `document` de la ventana que no se pudo abrir, esto debería funcionar en documentos que no son `<iframe>`

Comment: Es que OP debe explicar lo que quiere hacer. Yo sospecho que hay una mala práctica en su código o un error de lógica.

Comment: Creo que puede ser una de las restricciones que pone SO en los scripts, al igual que tampoco permite crear cookies o acceder a localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

debes utilizar el document.querySelectorAll para que te devuelva una lista

ejemplo:

```js
for(x of document.querySelectorAll('[bt-print]')){
x.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  alert(1);
var divToPrint=document.querySelector('[area-print="'+this.getAttribute('bt-print')+'"]');
var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.outerHTML+'</body></html>');
newWin.document.close();
});
}
```

```html
<div area-print="hola">hola</div>
<div area-print="chau">chau</div>

<button bt-print="hola">Hola</button>
<button bt-print="chau">Chau</button>
```

Nota: el editor no permite acceder a todas las funcionalidades como puden ser `window.open(), locastorage, coockie etc..` por ende va a marcar error .

Comment: Da errores este código.

Comment: Este código da error. Sospecho que el origen de problema aquí es **una mala práctica**. A ver si OP explica lo que quiere hacer, yo no logro encontrar el sentido de este código.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que hace este codigo es obtener el outerhtml de un div y mandarlo a una ventana para que esta ventana se imprima y al momento de cancelar o imprimir se cierre automaticamente, esto lo hago para por ejemplo imprimir un div en especifico sin usar reglas css simplemente imprimir el html del div